Permanent with present perfect
Will you understand the following context,
I have been reading the books for this three months, those books my Mom has bought for me every month since I was 16.
I love reading and I am pleased of having been bought for me the books.
In context I did not use past simple and I used present perfect to show the permanent.(my Mom has bought for me every month for a long time)
Is it correct?

I am confused about the timeline of events in this example - you say that you have been reading these books for three months, but then that you mom has bought the books every month since you were 16. Do you mean that you turned 16 three months ago? Or do you mean that your mom has bought you a book every month for a long time, but that you just started reading them three months ago? Or something else?

Reading books  that I meant my temporary action and those books was bought by Mom every months since I was 16.I want to say those books  was bought by Mom every months from I was 16 .Yes ,I want to say Mom has bought the books every months for a long time. Yes ,I just started reading three months ago. I am not sure , can I use like that to show permanent that long time action,  thats why I asked @Friendly Racoon

"just make a note yes or no"....   No   ...  Is that *really what you want?

Hello  @James K , I know to use past simple bought for me that makes clear the sentence  but I want to know instead of bought there can I use present perfect to show the regular action for a long time as permanent . I am not confused about permanent and temporary , I want to know that can I use directly has bought every months for a long time.My Mom is still buying for me the books.

Okay.  Please edit your question.  You asked for just "yes" or "no".  I think you want an explanation, so please edit your question to ask for an explanation.

There are a lot of mistakes in your paragraph - but, yes, it's correct to say "My Mom has been buying a book for me every month since I was sixteen", implying that she still is. (NB Every month, not months.)

Madam , Why I can't use my mom has bought for me every month since I was sixteen in this context , please explain me , I am confused  , I want to show permanent @Kate Bunting

(It's perfectly fine to address me as Kate.) Yes, "...my Mom has bought for me every month" would be correct as well. I must have been confused about which tense you were asking about.

Thanks a lot Madam! As usual you are the best @Kate Bunting

In short, your use of the present perfect is correct but the sentences overall are not. Here is one way a native speaker might say this:

My mom has bought books for me every month since I was 16. I have been reading them for the past three months. I love reading, and I am pleased that she bought the books for me.

There are several changes here from your original, and I am happy to answer questions about specific things if you ask in the comments. But since your overall question was about Present Perfect, I'll focus on that in this answer.
Present Perfect
Yes, your usage of the present perfect tense was excellent. Its main function is to show an action that started in the past and continues to the present, which makes sense in this context (with the clarification you gave in the comments above).
Here are some other examples of present perfect being used in similar contexts:

I have bought bread from that bakery every week since I moved here. It's delicious!

You have given me flowers on my birthday for the past five years.

My mom has worked as a doctor for her whole career.



I am glad that you explain to me for my question.Thanks a lot sir , I really appreciate your explanation @Friendly Racoon
